# How do I make GDAL use HDF4 formats?

Tags: homebrew, gdal, hdf

After manually installing the HDF4 library (it is not available with Homebrew), my GDAL (installed via Homebrew) does not support HDF4 file formats (`gdalinfo --formats`). How can I solve this problem?